# Why does vim use hjkl for cursor keys?

Tags: cursor-motions, history-of, keyboard-layout

Why use the keys <kbd>hjkl</kbd> on the same line instead of keys in a triangle like <kbd>wasd</kbd> for moving on video games?

Why not something equivalent with right hand, like <kbd>ijkl</kbd> or <kbd>pl;'</kbd>?

Comment: Check that Wikipedia page of [vi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi), it contains a picture of some ancient Unix machine [keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi#/media/File:KB_Terminal_ADM3A.svg) which explains, some keybindings.

Comment: Because `vim` is exempt from keeping up with technological advances :3

Comment: You can put four fingers of one hand on the hjkl keys, **comfortably**, and move the cursor all four directions without shifting fingers back and forth. If you really think about it, four in a row is the only cursor key layout consistent with human anatomy. The question is really how everyone else manages to get it wrong.

Comment: Actually it's not recommended to put your index on the `h` but rather on the `j` (that's why you have a "nipple" on the `j` key). Reason for that is that you will use `b` much more than `h` and having `;` accessible is handy in a lot of programming language (and with a shift, you have `:` which is ever more handy in Vim).

Comment: So the "moving the cursor around" position is shifted left one place from the "normal typing" position. This isn't a problem, at least not a big one. Twisting your hand until your fingers are in the shape of the WASD key group... that could cause actual pain.

Comment: I believe that it keeps you from taking your fingers off the keyboard, and moving them to the arrows or the mouse....but I'll take the wiser answers above thank you.

Comment: BTW, this topic is covered in the second top-voted question on [Unix SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34196/why-was-chosen-to-represent-the-home-directory)

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley I always though using <kbd>esdf</kbd> was a far better choise for "upside-down 'T'" cursor position. It just requires you to move the left middle finger one row up from the home row.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

From http://www.catonmat.net/blog/why-vim-uses-hjkl-as-arrow-keys/:

> When Bill Joy created the vi text editor he used the ADM-3A terminal, which had the arrows on hjkl keys. Naturally he reused the same keys and the rest is history!

[image]

Comment: This should still be on every keyboard ! :)

Comment: Now you've got me wondering what kind of terminal the guy who made emacs had...

Comment: @leeand00: A [Symbolics LISP Machine Space Cadet Keyboard](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-cadet_keyboard). The article explicitly talks about how the design of the keyboard influenced the design of Emacs, and it also compares it to the design of Vi with its ubiquitous Escape key, and the fact that the Escape was very conveniently located on the ADM-3A Terminal's keyboard. Well, on the Space Cadet Keyboard, there are the Control, Meta, Super, and Hyper keys which are *very* conveniently located, as well no less than 3 different Shift keys allowing to type over 8000 characters.

Comment: While this answer is correct as such, it sort of moves the question rather than answer it: "Why did the ADM-3A keyboard choose `hjkl` and not a more logical shape such as `ijkl`?"

Comment: @JörgWMittag: wow, the Space Cadet has the arrows on a different set of home row keys!

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: we didn't invent keyboard arrow location logic until the late 80s http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/30/Apple_Macintosh_ADB_Keyboard.jpg

Comment: @JacobKrall: I don't think those are navigation keys. They are actual arrow characters for writing mathematical formulae etc. (Or Smalltalk, which originally used `←` for assignment and `↑` for return, both of which were present on the Xerox keyboard layouts. Nowadays Smalltalk uses `:=` and `^`.) I believe, the navigation keys are the ones in the top right corner with the fingers pointing in different directions.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: that's actually the "Like" key for use on Facebook. the left and right keys are used for web browsing, and the "Dislike" key has been broken from overuse. /s

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Your new question is off-topic, though ;)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker my answer gives some information that may explain that (and remember that `^I` is tab.) - though I suppose in theory they could have used UHJK, if we assume that they only cared about maintaining the meaning of `^H` and `^J`.

Answer (score 28):

[Nobe4's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/9315/2920) is great, and explains why we use `hjkl` very well. However, it's really interesting to see the full keyboard, and a lot of strange things about vim make more sense when you can see the full keyboard it was designed on. For example, why does vi rely so heavily on the `esc` key, when it's in such a weird and uncomfortable place? This is why:

[image]

As you can see, `esc` is where tab is on most keyboards. `ctrl` is another key that is slightly awkward to reach, but in a very comfortable location on this keyboard (where caps lock usually is).

Comment: Did `vi` have a `<Leader>` mapping? I thought that was a later invention...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I think so, but I'm not actually sure. Vim's `:help <leader>` doesn't have the signature `{not in Vi}` text, and it does say vi had `:map` (although not `:noremap`), so I'm pretty sure that vi had leader. Even if it didn't, I would imagine the history of the vi keyboard would at least *somewhat* influence the design of vim.

Comment: It's also hard to find information on vi through google, since most of the results end up being about vim.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/utilities/vi.html and http://roguelife.org/~fujita/COOKIES/HISTORY/1BSD/exrefm.pdf are good references for vi (POSIX and historical, respectively). You can also download nvi, elvis, vile, or ex-vi (ex-vi is a descendant of the historical vi) and look at what they do or their documentation. There is no `<leader>` feature in vi.

Comment: Also, Vim was originally developed for the Amiga (backslash in its usual [ISO or Large Enter] position), and based on Stevie which was for the Atari ST (backslash in the lower right corner, past enter, but it didn't apparently support `:map` at all)

Comment: `"+y` / `"+p` look nicer on this keyboard, but still annoying

Answer (score 19):

As to why these arrows were printed on these keys... it's because they could be used with the control key for local cursor movement. Ctrl-H and Ctrl-J (backspace and line feed) are obvious, and an easy mnemonic even today. Ctrl-K is "vertical tab", but was sometimes used for reverse linefeed on pre-ANSI terminals. The use of Ctrl-L for a non-destructive cursor forward was probably chosen based on its keyboard location.

You may also have noticed in the picture of the keyboard in the other answer that "HOME" is on the `^`/`~` key. Of course, Ctrl-^ homes the cursor (sends to the top left of the screen, or bottom left, depending on mode).

These control mappings were also used for Wyse terminals, the Kermit protocol, and were supported in some versions of PC ANSI.SYS.

Sources:

- [The ADM-3A Operator's Manual](http://vt100.net/lsi/adm3a-om/), page 3-5 [pdf page 38] onward describes the control functions.
- [Terminfo database](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html) for other terminals; search for `kcuf1=^L` and `kcuu1=^K`

Comment: ^H, ^K – very enlightening, since today I'll easily remember that ^J moves down. I was never able to remember assignment of up-down reliably.

Comment: Wow I never knew Ctrl-J means linefeed