# Why is using arrow keys in normal mode considered bad practice?

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-movement

I have read it in many articles ([e.g.](http://kgrz.io/getting-started-with-using-vim.html)) that it's a bad practice to use arrow keys in normal mode. Could somebody explain why is it considered a wrong practice, if at all?

Comment: One good reason not to use hjkl is if you use another keyboard layout. For example, hjkl are not spatially correlated in Dvorak and thus are difficult to use.

Comment: @Kylos I use `hjkl` in Dvorak. It's definitely less sensible than on qwerty, but I don't know that I'd call it "difficult to use"; they're just keys, and it's not like it's hard to reach them or anything once you're used to it.

Comment: There are many myth why ``hjkl`` should be the best option for moving in a document. The truth is, some keyboards had the arrow keys on ``hjkl`` in the time when vi was created, so vi used the same keys in normal mode to match the keyboard layout. Here is an article with a photo of the keyboard: http://www.catonmat.net/blog/why-vim-uses-hjkl-as-arrow-keys/

Comment: Anything with a reputation for difficulty... attracts a certain sort of person. Crossfit, Vim, functional programming, veganism, etc. Now certainly not all people who take up one of those activities is of that sort, but they show up disproportionately often. And part of the allure for that person is the *difficulty of the activity itself*. Things that lower the bar to entry are anathema to them: it makes them less special. There are reasons to prefer `hjkl`. Good ones. But they get inflated to the status of dogma, at least in part, because people have to feel like they're better than others.

Comment: @Kylos I agree that `hjkl` are not the best ever in dvorak. But as a dvorak user I can find them a bit handy since they are paired together: as in `jk` on one side of the board; and `hl`  on the other side.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Actually this is not a bad practice.

A lot of people (*including Vim's doc as @B Layer's answer shows*) argue that you shall not use arrow keys because it makes your hands move from the home row (the second line of your keyboard where you have <kbd>h</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>l</kbd>) and that make you less efficient.

This is (IMO at least) a bad result from vim "purists" circle jerk: new users follow this blindly, some even disable the arrow keys and then they complain that they are not as efficient as before.

The only real rule to use vim is to use it efficiently: if you feel more comfortable using <kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Right</kbd> than <kbd>h</kbd> and <kbd>l</kbd>  be it, use the arrow keys. Vim even has `set mouse=a` option if you want to use a mouse!

Once you get used to vim and get better with the different available motions (<kbd>f</kbd>, <kbd>t</kbd>, <kbd>,</kbd>, <kbd>;</kbd>, <kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>b</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>, and basically everything in [`:h quickref`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickref.txt.html#quickref)) you might realize that you don't use arrow keys that much. And if you still use them, it's not a problem, use what you are most efficient with.

**Note** That the argument of don't leave the home row for more efficiency is not that good in my opinion: If you take a look at [Why does vim use hjkl](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/9313/1841) you'll see that these keys were chosen because there weren't any arrow keys when Vi was written. One could argue that maybe if the keyboards were different at this time no one would consider not using the arrow keys a good practice.

Comment: I often found myself bending my wrist very badly to reach the arrow keys because I was so used to them. I ended up disabling the arrow keys to get myself used to `hjkl` just to relief some pain from my wrist.

Comment: I'd like to point out that this only makes sens on QWERTY keyboards. For some layouts hjkl can be a real pain.

Comment: You can make use of both options: whether you pick hjkl or arrows, you can bind the other set of up/down keys to move by on-screen lines and not file lines. It helps when editing files with long lines.

Comment: I hadn't realized before reading your answer that I hardly use hjkl and arrow keys because I got used to the advanced motion commands you mention. Good point!

Comment: I used to feel this way. You don't really notice an inefficiency that's burned into muscle memory until you've burned the efficient alternative into muscle memory too. For me, attitude on `hjkl` vs. arrows followed the same path as attitude on `vi` vs "user friendly" editor. I became proficient in `vi` first, and only after the fact started to appreciate it as efficient. Until I really internalized `vi` semantics, normal editors felt more efficient to me, and until I started to internalize `hjkl`, switching my hand to the arrows keys felt more efficient too.

Comment: However much I appreciate your to-my-eye correct answer, could I please prevail upon you as a fellow moderator and *vi* aficionado into trying your hardest to find some less “seedy” alternative phrasing to *circle jerk* that does not evoke the vividly disturbing image of a trouser-less ring of boys or men all masturbating together in each other’s company‽ *Pretty please?* :)

Comment: Ack! @tchrist that gratuitous word painting of the offending phrase has made your comment the thing I'd personally like to see cleaned up. LOL.

Comment: I do not like using the arrow keys on a normal keyboard, but on a 60% keyboard the arrow keys are on the WASD cluster. To me this works better than hjkl and the arrow keys (which I don't have). 

But I do kind of understand that the arrow keys are annoying to use.

Comment: I use the arrow keys. A lot. I have remapped them to navigate the quickfix list when I lint my code.

Answer (score 41):

I don't know if this is really relevant any more, but I'm an old-timer so here's a bit of history.

In the old days, VT100 terminals had arrow keys, but pressing one transmitted an escape sequence like `<ESC>[A` for up, `<ESC>[B` for down, etc.
Also, being a serial terminal communicating at 9600 baud, it was possible for the user to press the keys too fast to transmit the whole sequence which would cause one key press to interrupt the sequence of the previous key press and confuse vi.

This would cause vi to inexplicably go into insert mode and insert [B[B[B[B[B[B into your file if you held down the down arrow.  I say inexplicably because there's nothing about this sequence that should enter insert mode and the fact that each sequence starts with an ESC character should have exited insert mode.  But still, it would insert garbage.  Not always - just when you were in a hurry.

One quickly got tired of this and decided to just stick to the `hjkl` keys.

Comment: For whatever reason, TCP terminal programs *still* use escape-based arrow keys, and still do not have any 100%-reliable way of distinguishing between pressing the escape key versus sending the first byte of an arrow-key escape sequence.

Comment: @supercat They _do_ have a reliable way to distinguish those.  It's called using [SC81T](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-C1-_8-Bit_-Control-Characters).  The problem is more that many programs don't negotiate that and some terminals likely don't support it.

Comment: @jamessan: If I read that right, you're suggesting that the reliable way of distinguishing escape from arrow keys is to not use escape-based arrow keys, which ties in with my "for whatever reason" comment about programs still using escape-based arrow keys.

Comment: Hmm, I have an old IBM terminal that can emulate a VT100, might have to try this out

Comment: I can certainly confirm that this was true, at least way-back-when, as during the 80s we had to put up signs in the undergrad terminal room not to use the arrow keys in *vi* for this very reason. They kept messing up their files when the tty driver dropped interrupts.

Comment: <i>... there's nothing about this sequence that should enter insert mode ...</i> —  Yes if you're just typing down arrow, but not quite true if there's at least one up arrow in the sequence. Since the up arrow is `<ESC>[A`, if you hit up arrow and then down arrow fast enough that they overlap, and vi sees the sequence `<ESC>[<ESC>[BA`, then it will be seen as "invalid escape code `<ESC>[`, then valid code `<ESC>[B` which means down-arrow, then `A` which means append". And so now you're in insert mode at the end of the line. Though why later `<ESC>`s don't leave insert mode, I don't know.

Answer (score 30):

While I agree with @statox that no one should be chastised, shunned, excommunicated, or tarred-and-feathered if they choose to use the arrow keys...use your software however you see fit...I wouldn't exude as much of a laissez-faire attitude if I were giving guidance to an open-minded new user. I'd pretty strongly recommend that they start with following best practices. They are "best practices" for a reason...they've been employed to good effect by lots of people who came before you and me.

Heck, even [Vim's own help nudges you in that direction](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_02.txt.html#hjkl), though not without hyperbole ("*greatly* slow down")...

> You can also move the cursor by using the arrow keys.  If you do,
>   however, you greatly slow down your editing because to press the arrow
>   keys, you must move your hand from the text keys to the arrow keys.
>   Considering that you might be doing it hundreds of times an hour, this
>   can take a significant amount of time.

There's also the fact that whatever choices you make at the start may become habits that are difficult to break if you want to change in the future. So all else being equal why not adopt a recommended habit now rather than take the chance that using arrow keys *is* inefficient or carpal-killing?

All in all, consider giving an honest effort to doing things without arrow keys. After a reasonable amount of time if you just can't live without up/down/left/right...don't.

*...is what I would say to a new user who was interested in my opinion. Don't take it personally if you don't agree (I'm talking to you, downvoter).*

Comment: Even if you accept that it is indeed better than arrow keys (I am not even convinced it is) it is somewhere is at the bottom of the list of all the possible "best practices". I would argue that there are many *many* more important things than using hjkl.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I don't think it's necessary to rank best practices. Unless you have a strong desire to use arrow keys why not do as Vim recommends? Particularly if you are new to Vim...we all know how hard it is to change the way we do something once it's ingrained.

Comment: "you greatly slow down your editing" - that seems like quite the exaggeration to me... nevertheless I agree it's worth giving it a try. It's just honestly not important enough to war over.

Comment: @Shadow Agreed on all points. (I don't think any of us are warring here, btw.)

Comment: @BLayer no not here - this is the most civil discussion on the topic I think I've seen. But wars certainly have been fought...

Comment: `don't think it's necessary to rank best practices` Well, it seems to me that we should focus on the things that give us the best value in life, given that resources are finite and that life is short. I happen to know the hjkl keys be heart due to a misspent childhood playing rogue, larn, angband, etc. on a laptop without numpad, but some people spent their childhood better, and will have to "unlearn" arrow keys regardless. I think that learning motions, ranges, etc. are a much more useful way to spend time.

Comment: Some of it depends on how you like to learn I should think. If you want to learn slowly/incrementally while still maintaining close to your previous efficiency you might do such a "cost-benefit analysis" of BPs. I lean more towards going all-in. I'm also influenced by spending much of my career as a programmer where my managers generally wouldn't have been enthusiastic that I was following just the subset of company's BPs that I considered most beneficial. :)

Comment: One could also argue that reaching for the ESC key, in order to be able to use hjkl, on a PC keyboard interrupts touch typing for many users just as reaching for the arrow keys will?

Comment: @rackandboneman No doubt it takes you away from the home row but I've found that over time I've gotten so quick with it, barely more than a flick of the wrist, that I don't really use this mapping any more:  `:inoremap jk <Esc>`.

Comment: For what it's worth, my transition from arrow keys to `hjkl` took all of maybe a month of *occasional* focused effort during which it was a mild nuisance but didn't hamper productivity too much because I only did it during times when it was easy to switch to it without significant cognitive overhead (slow scrolling through code, etc). Most of the other time I let myself fall through to arrow-key muscle-memory auto-pilot, at first. It gradually took less and less conscious effort, so it became natural to practice it more and more. Now I *hate* whenever I can't use `hjkl` in a program.

Comment: (con't) My point is, the effort expended on learning `hjkl` was nearly negligible, especially after re-warping my mind to`vi`'s ways after having grown up in a world of Microsoft Windows GUI conventions. Don't do it if you don't want to, but if you don't mind trying it out, it need not be a frustrating experience: work your way up from just replacing *single* arrow movement being replaced by an `hjkl` movement whenever you remember, don't force it when you're otherwise focused, and you'll find yourself naturally comfortable with both eventually, enabling a more meaningful comparison.

Comment: @rackandboneman Depends on the keyboard, but generally speaking I think this is very true. I always map my Caps Lock to Ctrl, and pretty quickly fell into the habit of using Ctrl-[ in lieu of Escape, which feels far less disruptive to me. I also use Ctrl-o for one-offs very often.

Comment: In my experience, my RSI is **dramatically** worse when I have to use an editor without vi keybindings and in particular it's when I'm using the arrow keys that I notice the worst of it. So there's that.

Answer (score 16):

Other answers have said that the efficiency loss from moving your hands from the home row isn't that big a deal, and I mostly agree.  However, what *is* a big deal is when you are learning vim, always using arrow keys to avoid switching back into normal mode.

In other words, using a single <kbd>←</kbd> where you would have used a single <kbd>h</kbd> isn't a huge loss in productivity, but using <kbd>←</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> where you could have used <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> *is* a huge loss.

That's why people tell you to avoid the arrow keys when you're learning vim, because it forces you to learn normal mode instead of never leaving insert mode.  Normal mode is where all your efficiency gains are.

Comment: +1. In other words: "Don't use the arrow keys, and don't use `hjkl`." (Retaining the intentional hyperbole.)

Comment: Actually, instead of 10 times `←` you could have used `1` `0` `←` or, even simpler, `Home`. The latter works even in Windows Notepad.

Answer (score 7):

A more precise statement might be **"using the arrow keys is bad practice *while trying to learn vim better*"**. People new to vim are used to using the arrow keys to move around and so don't learn `hjkl`, thus not getting the chance to see if this is preferable.

Personally, after gaining some general familiarity with vim, I [disabled the arrow keys](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5851/how-to-disable-arrow-keys-in-vim) for a while to get the hang of `hjkl` and reenabled them later to simplify my `.vimrc`. The conventional wisdom holds in my case; once I knew how to use both `hjkl` and the arrow keys, I found myself almost exclusively using the former.

Comment: I disagree. Like [this blog](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/07/29/everyone-who-tried-to-convince-me-to-use-vim-was-wrong/) says, that "all or nothing" approach for beginners helps cause the "user unfriendly" reputation of vim. New users start, get bogged down and overwhelmed and (not surprisingly) conclude vim is an unholy mess and switch back to an editor where they can be decently productive. -- If you're learning to swim, you don't throw yourself off the boat into the open ocean. It's perfectly acceptable to dog-paddle around the kiddy pool until you get comfortable with the water.

Comment: ... not to say that disabling arrow keys won't work for people. But it's a "I like vim and want to learn how to use it better" step, not a "I'm new to vim and want to learn how to use it" step.

Answer (score 7):

There are two main reasons why people say you shouldn't use the arrow keys.  Some claim that hjkl is preferred because it keeps your hands on the home row, which isn't *false*, but also doesn't matter.  Others, including myself, would say you shouldn't use the arrow keys if you're moving more than a few characters, but you shouldn't use hjkl, either.

The important thing isn't *which* keys you're using, but rather *how many*.  If you want to move to the beginning of the word, you don't hit `hhh`; you hit `b`.  End of the word is `e`, not `llll`.  Beginning of the line: `0`, end of the line: `$`.  And anything further, `/search` for the text that exists where you want to go. (or whichever of the advanced movement commands you prefer).

But any time you find yourself typing the same key more than twice in a row, there's a better way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

The usual answer involves efficiency.  You've likely been trained over the years to employ touch typing, which employs keeping your hands on asdf and jkl;.  A vast majority of the key bindings in Vi are designed around this fact, including the hjkl movement commands.

Personally I actually use both.  I use hjkl when I'm actively editing large sections of text, and the arrow keys when scrolling through log files (and |, g, and / when I'm doing spot edits throughout a file).  This just happens to be what works well for me, and in a case like this, that's what really matters.

Answer (score 2):

Long time ago, many terminals did not have arrow keys, or did not have all four of them.  Software systems that needed navigation normally provided some sort of navigation approach without relying on arrow keys, and vi's hjkl is a canonical example.  (Another classical example is WordStar's ^E-^S-^X-^D.)  As keyboard navigation's utility became increasingly obvious, more and more new terminals began to come with arrow keys, and software systems often mapped these to the old ways of navigation.  However, this provided a portability concern of sorts: if children trained at schools were to come to rely on such a fancy new-fangled feature as arrow keys, the thinking was, they might not be able to be productive on the — once common — keyboards without arrow keys.

So, teachers of courses into basic computing began to cautiously warn students to learn to use the lowest common denominator so as to maximise their employability.  And this practice has long outlived any reasons that it may once have had.

In modern implementations of vi, the main reason to prefer hjkl is that it's slightly faster to use keys already under your hand than moving your hand to wherever your arrow keys are.  The downside of avoiding the context switch of your hand, of course, is that you may need to perform a context switch of vi.  Nowadays, when humans are very rarely treasured by typing speed, whether you do one or the other is pretty much a matter of personal preference, and there's nothing inherently bad about using arrow keys anymore, if there ever was.